# Using a local class variable in other class destructor

Tags: c++, static

I'm programming some "extra' version of Rock, Paper and Scissors.
It's some kind of hybridization between chess and RPS.
Pawns meet each other on board, fight according to RPS rules and whoever loses die (gets deleted).
Each square on board has 2 pointers, for each pawn. when a pawn dies, I want him the be able to nullptr his pointer in square, so I made static matrix of square struct (which has 2 pointers of pawns), so I can access it and nullptr the pointer, but I can't use local class variable.
class point {

```
char x, y;
```

pawn class:

```
class game;

class pawn {
    point *location;
    char type;
    char currentState = 0;

public:
    ~pawn()
    {
        delete(location);
    }

};
```

and for game class :

```
typedef char score;


typedef struct Square {
            pawn *p1, *p2;
        }square;

        class game {

            player *player1, *player2;
            score p1 = 0, p2= 0;
            static square board[10][10];
        };
```

I thought of coding a pawn destructor like :

```
~pawn () {
(game().getBoard())[x][y] = nullptr;
delete (location); }
```

Is there any way to do so? maybe change the "#include" files order or something? (I have about 10 files in this project).

Comment: What fraction of the posted code is relevant to your question? Please cut it down to the [minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I've minimized it. 
Long story short, I want to use class Game functions inside Pawn's destructor, How can I do that?

Comment: Thanks! Now it's clear it isn't complete, because I have no idea what `point *location` is or what it represents. And where do `x` and `y` come from? Anyway, assuming the semantics of  `location` are correct, what's the actual problem? What happened that makes you think you need to reorder includes? Is there a compile error? What does it say?

Comment: x,y comes from using location function, maybe I should've been more clear.
The compiler errors are :
C2027 - use of underfined type 'game'
C2228 - left of .getBoard must have class/struct/union

Comment: The point of a minimal _complete_ example is that it's _complete_. Otherwise you end up with these comment chains, fishing for details one by one, that should have been in the question from the beginning. The point of _verifiable_ examples is that I can build it myself to reproduce your problem and also to verify a fix works. Everything about this question is asking me to guess what your problem might be, in order to guess what might fix it.

Comment: Thank you! It's working now ;] !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(game().getBoard())[x][y] = nullptr;
```

`game()` is creating an instance of your class and then calling a function to, presumably, get a reference to the static `board` member.

While that may work, you probably want to call `game::getBoard()` instead and make `getBoard()` static if it is not so yet.

Now, it is unclear where `x` and `y` are coming from -- for sure they cannot be the non-static member variables in `point` as shown.

Comment: How do I need to write it?
if "static square board[10][10];" is my board. how will I declare the function? that way "static square getBoard() { return (&board); };"

Comment: `game::board` is the name of your board, but as currently declared it's private.

Comment: How do I return a referance to Board? Compiler doesn't let me write it as : static square &getBoard() { return (board); };

Comment: @AmitBL: `board` is a 2D array of `square`s, not a single `square` object.

Comment: Huh still shows the same error... I can't use Game class function insides Pawn class

Comment: @AmitBL: I am guessing you are just forward declaring the Game class before the Pawn class. You need to move your function definitions outside of the class if you have a cyclic dependency.

Comment: Actually you're right, I actually do a forward declaration of Game class in pawn.h file. I can't move function ouside of classes because it's an assignment for school, i'll get lower grade /=

Comment: @AmitBL: Try to re-think the design of your application. In general, you want to avoid cyclic dependencies between classes, static member functions/variables, complex destructors, etc. You can simplify it a lot!